# Calling Word print dialog from Powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell, winforms, ms-word

I have this script which creates and modifies a Word document:

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection

$Selection.Font.Size = 16
$Selection.Font.Bold = 1
$Selection.TypeText("DATA")
$Selection.Font.Bold = 0
$Selection.Font.Size = 12
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.TypeText("Name: `vLast Name:")

$Report=$PSScriptRoot + "\test.docx"
$Document.SaveAs([ref]$Report,[ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)

$Word.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$word)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable word
```

**Is there any way to open up the print dialog box in Word and implement it in the script above?**
I tried with `Start-Process -FilePath .\test.docx -Verb Print` but UI has been shown just briefly and closes immediately without allowing me to do any operation.

Unfortunately, `PrintDialog` form is not an option for what I need to do.
I would like to be able to call the print dialog of MS Word.

To be clear, the one in this picture:
[image]

Comment: If the PrintDialog is not an option, then which print dialog do you want?

Comment: @Theo, I would like to call the print dialog of MS Word, if possible. So I can edit the document through powershell, and then print it from MS Word